# Hemorrhoids on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, health-safety-shmira, bathroom, blood

What are the Halachos about one with Hemorroids on Shabbos?

Is he allowed to use the bathroom/wipe, as this might cause him to bleed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Shulchan Aruch [328, 22-23](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1599), see also [sayf 26](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1600). To use a wipe seems as in sayif 22, to clean the injury, the blood is generally already here and it is not really a new bleeding. "Migh cause him bleed" is not psik resha and is Davar She'eino mitkaven, according to Rabbi Shim'on it is allowed and for RI it is not DeOrayita, there is also a problem of Kevod Habriot because of the soiled place. If he makes a bath because pain, it is an additionnat to allow. Ointment with oil is also allowed.